# Number of Pairs of Subsets

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of Pairs $(A,B)$ of subsets of $[n]$ such that $A ⊆ B$?

I just need clarification in my thought process. My professor's wording at times can through me off. I just want to know if I am on the right track.

We will have $3$ regions:

**1**.Outside $B$

**2**.Inside $A$

**3**. Inside $B$, Outside $A$

I believe the number of pairs is $3^n$ but I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you define what you mean by $[n]$ please?  perhaps you mean $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$?

Comment: Yeah sorry its my professor lazy way of notating the set of all positive integers put to n.

Comment: It seems to me that you had a great idea the way that you wrote it initially.  For each $i\in \{1,2,...,n\}$, you can put $i$ in one of those three regions.  For each different choice you make, it gives you a different result for $(A,B)$.  Might want to word it well to explain why every possibility is representable this way, and why each representation gives rise to a unique possibility.

Comment: @JMoravitz: $[n]$ is a standard notation for $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Eduardo: It’s not laziness.

Comment: I was think of it as placing objects, which is how i got 3^n as a solution. The way i was seeing was that if i place ball 8 into a region lets say in region 2 i have 3 regions to chose for each given [n]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right; for each element in $[n]$, you have 3 choices:

1) Include it in A $\hspace{.2 in}$ 2) Include it in B, but not in A $\hspace{.2 in}$ 3) Include it in neither; so this gives $3^n$ pairs.

---

Another way to do this would be to let $k$ be the number of elements in A, where $0\le k\le n$.

There are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose the elements of A, and then there are
$2^{n-k}$ ways to select a subset of the remaining $n-k$ elements to include with A to get B;

so this gives a total of $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n2^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}=3^n$ pairs using the Binomial Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Using your approach you can first decide the number of elements, $k$, that we want $B$, we can the place $k$ elements into $B$ in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways and for each of these elements we have the option of putting it in $A$ or putting it outside of $A$. This gives that for each given $k$ there are $\binom{n}{k}2^k$ such pairs of subsets. Summing over all valid $k$ and applying the binomial theorem gives the result of $3^n$.